# Ответы, которые ответами не являются

Tags: обсуждение, moderation

Мне кажется, что [это](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/25279/) никоим образом не ответ:

> Здесь по несколько орфограмм. Что именно интересует?

Я поднял тревогу "не является ответом", но проверяющие посчитали это "спорным". Досадно.

#### Почему следует удалять такие посты?

1. Они мешают поиску -- в частности тем, кто ищут вопросы без ответов
2. Они мешают автоматической уборке сайта. Старые неотвеченные вопросы с отрицательным рейтингом автоматически удаляются через месяц. Этот низкокачественный [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/25241/) был бы уже удалён, если бы не имелось "ответа".
3. Они подают плохой пример использования сайта. Если на сайте вопросов и ответов теряется различение вопросов и ответов, то это уже нечто иное.

Answer (score 3):

Со страницы проверок можно зайти в историю проверок из очереди "Посты низкого качества" и посмотреть, кто как голосует. Если вы видите, что какой-то пользователь или пользователи неверно понимают назначение очереди, можете попытаться провести с ними воспитательные беседы и объяснить, в чём разница между ответом и комментарием, и почему важно голосовать правильно. Если пользователь не помешан на идее "нужно оставлять всё", то, возможно, этого будет достаточно.

Также можно попытаться обратиться к модераторам, чтобы они наставили пользователя на путь истинный. Но, как я понимаю, из модераторов здесь только Николас (и, возможно, забеглые модераторы), так что на этот вариант рассчитывать не особо приходится. Нужно больше суровых модераторов.

Answer (score 0):

Я помню этот вопрос. Помню и то, как такой ответ появился. 
Тогда люди осваивались в новой среде и использовали поле ответ как комментарий.
Комментарий этот, кстати, вполне там уместен. Вопрос был задан бестолково.

В данном конкретном случае такой ответ, возможно, стоит удалить. Но все ваши рассуждения - ненужная патетика. Просто "сообщество" с вами не согласилось. у меня это постоянно происходит.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не правы в отношении рассуждений, они абсолютно верные.

Comment: Как скажете... Но я остаюсь при своем мнении. Могу разве уточнить. **Если речь идет об удалении одного конкретного вопроса, то все рассуждения тут излишни.** Конкретнее надо быть. А если дело в самих рассуждениях и касается только общих подходов и ссылка на вопрос дана ради примера, то этот пример неудачен. Ответ был вполне к месту, его стоило просто поправить. Или перенести в комментарии. Я, кстати, уже десятками ответы на удаление пометил.

Answer (score 0):

Приведенный вами пример, безусловно, не является ответом. Такие сообщения должны публиковаться в комментариях.

Если вы замечаете подобные ответы, пожалуйста, отмечайте их тревогой.